# Mac update_dyld_shared_cache error in the terminal

Tags: macos, caching, terminal, root, dyld

I had an error message in my terminal a few days ago:

> dyld: shared cached file was built against a different libSystem.dylib, ignoring cache.
>   to update dyld shared cache run: 'sudo update_dyld_shared_cache' then reboot.

I looked it up on the internet and I found that rebooting in safe mode and rebooting again can make this disappear but it was temporary since today, the same error message came back

The solutions seems to be

> sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force

But when I execute this command, I have around 50 lines of errors appearing:

> update_dyld_shared_cache: for arch i386, can't put /usr/lib/libutil.dylib in shared cache because it is not owned by root
>   update_dyld_shared_cache: for arch i386, can't put /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib in shared cache because it is not owned by root
>   ... 
>   update_dyld_shared_cache: for arch x86_64, can't put /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib in shared cache because it is not owned by root
>   ...

Has anyone encountered this problem, and managed to solve it ?
If it can help, I'm on Mac OS 10.9.5

Thank you for your help

**Edit:**
The issue solved itself with Yosemite

Comment: Same here, was able to get rid of it for a bit by doing a Safe Mode restart than a regular restart, but it comes back.... could use some help with this.

Answer (score 14):

Open Disk Utility, click on Repair Disk Permissions, and then try running `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache -force` again. Worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: I upgraded my os from OSX 10.10.2 to 10.10.4 and saw the issue that the OP reported.  Did the steps mentioned above and it worked like a champ.

Comment: Some people suggest going into safe mode and rebooting, this will only temporarily take care of the problem. Repairing Disk Permissions is the way to go, thanks!

Answer (score -3):

if you are getting this error, the owner of the file is not set properly.
so change the owner of the file by using **chown** command, look into below for example

got to terminal and type following command :

**chown /usr/lib/libutil.dylib**

**chown /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib**

**chown /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib**

good luck

Comment: the commands they way they are here don't do anything. You have to say to whom you are passing ownership.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but you forgot to mention that you have to do it as root.